# TreeView not showing plus/minus sign with child nodes

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a treeview that is bound to a class called Book that has an ObservableCollection of Accounts with the Account class holding a collection of subaccounts (type Account).

Everything is working correctly; however, when I add subaccounts it doesn't show the +/- sign on the parents with children.  I'm thinking it's because I used templates and must be missing something.  Any ideas?

Shows up like:

```
A
  a
B
C
  c
    c
```

But I need:

```
-A
  a
+B
-C
  -c
    c
```

Here's the code:

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}">
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Account}" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Subaccounts}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
      <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" 
                   Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick" />
    </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

I was using a List instead of an ObservableCollection in my Account class.  Naturally this caused it to fail.